# Data Base Query - I have a two table A and B. I have to fetch the data only from

Tags: mysql, database

I have a two table A and B. I have to fetch the data only from A table which is not matching with B table(means Uncommon Data from both the table.). But output should be only from Table A.

Table Value A
             1, 2 ,3,4,5,6

Table Value B
             1,2,7,8,9,0

---

**Out put should Be Below mentioned data**

3
 4
 5
 6

Comment: `Select tableA.value from tableA inner join tableB on tableA.value!=tableB.value`

Comment: it will show the B table data also. we need only table A value.

Comment: SQL 101: `Select a.value from tableA a left join tableB b on a.value=b.value where b.value is null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, may work for you;)

```
select *
from tablea a
where not exists(select 1 from tableb b where a.value = b.value)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9679/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablea` (
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tablea` (`value`) VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableb` (
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

INSERT INTO `tableb` (`value`) VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (7),
    (8),
    (9),
    (0);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from tablea a
where not exists(select 1 from tableb b where a.value = b.value)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9679/1/0)**:

```
| value |
|-------|
|     3 |
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE _value NOT IN 
(SELECT _value FROM TableB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN to get the desired result.

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

```
select a.value
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.value = b.value where b.value is null;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9679/7)

**Result**

```
| value |
|-------|
|     3 |
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
```